# Oracle VB /dev/mapper/rhel-root 100% full

Tags: rhel, virtualbox, disk-usage

I can't figure out the solution. I tried to do `pvcreate /dev/sda3` but it's showing me an error: Device /dev/sda3 not found.
I was following this: [Oracle VM Vitualbox - Extend centos root file system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469910/oracle-vm-vitualbox-extend-centos-root-file-system)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, your root filesystem is full -- you can try removing some files to free some space up (cleaning various caches, e.g. running `yum clean all` can also help, related: [Tracking down where disk space has gone on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125429/tracking-down-where-disk-space-has-gone-on-linux)) or add a new disk to your system (or resize your existing one) and then use one of the howtos for extending your LVM setup. `pvcreate /dev/sda3` returns error because you don't have `sda3` partition in your system. The howto you linked is for situation where you have some free space on your disk not used by existing partitions, that's not your case, you have 20 GiB drive and `sda1` and `sda2` use all of it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I thought to delete some files from the root system but I am afraid I might delete some important files. Can you please suggest which files could be unnecessary in this situation? I am using virtual box on my laptop. Should I do howto on adding new disk to virtualbox?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. ```yum clean all``` deleted ```Cleaning repos: rhel-7-server-rpms``` and now the root file system is 40% empty.

Comment: Is there a permanent way to add more disk space to the root file system or resizing the existing one?

Comment: Good to hear `yum clean all` helped. To add more space permanently you need either second disk or resize the existing one (disks in VMs can be resized), you can check [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106233/extending-resizing-fedora-guest-os-root-drive-in-virtualbox) for details.